# How to use a git remote for synchronization and backup?

Tags: git, synchronization, backup, git-remote

I am currently writing my thesis and want to use git to have not just backup, but also version control.
I have two workplaces, and an basically 2 online servers, as shown in the following chart.
[image]

Until now, I have just synchronized the office-computer and the laptop by synchronizing one of them with the backup folder on the backup server and subsequently comparing the other workstation with the backup server (which occasionally leads to conflicts if a file has been changed on both workstations).
Now I want to add the version control using git. I would like to have master repository (let's call it master) on the remote server, where on the workstations there are local repositories (let's call them slave_office and slave_laptop) and changes on each side are pushed to the remote repository.
My idea is this: When I finish my work on one workstation (say office), I will commit and push the changes to the remote repository, and then start the synchronization. When I want to use the laptop to work, I will first pull the changes from the remote repository and then start the synchronization. Then, the local files will be the same as on the backup server. Then, after finishing work, I would use the same order as before: First commit/push to the repository, then start the backup synchronization. Using this scheme, after pulling from the remote repo and synchronizing, I should have 4 identical copies of the project on office computer, backup server, remote repo and laptop, right?
(To avoid confusion, I should note why I use 2 servers: the backup server contains also private files that I don't want to share, whereas the git project should also be kind of "publicly" available on the remote server, which can be accessed by colleagues.)

My question is now:

1. Is this a "good" solution or is this way of combining synchronization and version control prone to create errors or other sources of discomfort?
2. How do I set up such a system. I am a git noob somehow, and ,although I used git a long time ago in a very simply setup and I am somewhat familiar with the basic commands, I am struggling with telling git, where the different repositories are and which is the remote. At the moment, I am stuck trying to get the files from the local repository cloned to the remote repository ("pathspec did not match any files"). I would be grateful for a kind of walkthrough.
   Thank you very much!

Comment: I recommend to add a hook on the master git server to mirror the git to another server.

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with hooks. Do you suggest to always copy the recent version of the master git server (after a push from either of the local stations) to the backup server? Then, I guess, the backup synchronization would always run into conflicts, because both local and master git repository changed. The backup is, in most of the cases, not only a backup, but also a sync that relies on checking which side of the backup has changed and which has not. That system would have to be replaced for the git stuff to always overwrite the files in the backup with those from the git server, right?

Comment: I speak about mirror, not copy. Which git server are you using ? Using to upstream can be quite a mess and hard to automatize, mainly in case of slit brain, I think you should have one master and a slave on read only. If the master go away, promote the slave to master